# IBM equivalent of SQL Server's DATEFROMPARTS()

Tags: sql

Is there an IBM SQL equivalent to the T-SQL `DATEFROMPARTS` function?

I'm trying to create a date `yyyy-mm-dd` from 3 columns of `char` type that contain year, month (1-12) and day (1-31).

I'm trying to avoid having to examine the days and months cols by using a `CASE` statement to change a `'1'` to a `'01'` and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE('2001-9-2') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: It looks like this is converting a string to a date type. My dates are stored in three columns as chars.  I want to concatenate the columns to get a character string, not a date, of the format YYYY-MM-DD. The days and months need to have 2 chars, but they're stored as one where there is no leading zero.

Comment: This turned out to be what I needed.  Select date(gmtdy || '-' ||  gmtdm || '-' ||  gmtdd) as transDate returns the format YYYY-MM-DD that I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(year || '-' || month || '-' || day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: I only want YYYY-MM-DD, not hrs, min, sec.  I don't need a date time format, just a string is fine, but I'm exporting the results to a .CSV file, so either should work if I can get rid of the hrs, mins, secs.  Tried adding a third param of 0 which the docs seem to say leaves them off, but didn't work.

Comment: `datefromparts()` returns a date, not a string, so your question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry if unclear, I said either datetime or string works, because I'm exporting the results to a .CSV file, so it becomes a string.  I just need to know how to truncate the result from to_date() to just the YYYY-MM-DD format, it doesn't matter if it's a date type or not.